# Traverse two links in OrientDB

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb

I'm really new to graph databases and trying to work with OrientDB.

I am using the document DB and I have something like:

projects <--> sources --> subsets

How do I get the subsets linked to sources of a specific project?

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
(select from (traverse sources.subsets from #project-rid))
```

Or should I use two traverse?

```
(select from (traverse subsets from (traverse sources from #project-rid)))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you used document or graph api?

Comment: Oh sorry. Question edited, I am using the document database.

Answer (score 0):

Traverse is useful on variable length depth. If it's known just cross them by using dot (.) notation.

```
select expand( sources.subsets ) from #project-rid
```

Comment: Seems like "EXPAND" is not recognized in my setup. In which version has it been released?

Comment: You can use FLATTEN with release older than 1.6